# Does the new operator or constructor block other threads in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, constructor, new-operator

I am wondering if invoking a constructor blocks other threads in the program? I was looking into concurrency report and found a long thread blocking other threads, and it's stack always has a constructor in it.

**EDIT:**

After the investigation, I found out, that the lock occurred because of the DB calls from another request (I ran an ASP.NET app).

To the question, as I found out in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx), memory allocation does not block threads, except when GC is invoked, as Servy pointed out.

Comment: What happens in the constructor?

Comment: Calling DB through entity framework. I was looking what I could optimize, and found out, that the thread was blocking other threads while inside the constructor. I also noticed just now, that the actual blocking occurs while inside a linq statement.

Comment: Static constructors block other threads; is the ctor static?

Comment: I'm aware about static constructors, it's not.

Comment: This rather depends on how much info you get out of your profiler.  It it doesn't show CLR internals (heap lock and GC) or unmanaged code (dbase and network contention) then it may well blame the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  It's possible for this specific constructor to be doing something that is causing other threads to block, but the act of calling a constructor doesn't, in and of itself, block all other threads.

One thing you may be noticing though is that the garbage collector does need to block the execution of all threads when it's running.  If you have a thread that is allocating lots and lot of objects, to the point that it's causing GC collections more than is desirable, you could be blocking your threads for noticeable periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on *concrete context*. Constructor is just another method, with special duty to construct (allocate memory) for your instance. You can construct object inside 
another thread, or block thread inside constructor, but it has nothing to do with constructor itself. Blocking is about a *flow* of your program.